# Cannot start RESTful Web Service IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I have been folowing [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) guide to build a RESTful web service.

I'm using IntelliJ with a gradle project, the content of build.gradle is:

```
group 'SpringTest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Here's the main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MainController.class, args);
    }
}
```

and here's the MainController:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MainController
{
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test()
    {
        return "Test success!";
    }
}
```

Upon trying to run it using SpringBoot configuration (same for the Application) the following Exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
    at testserver.Application.main(Application.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

How can I run the server in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main method you're running the wrong class:

```
SpringApplication.run(MainController.class, args);
```

Should be:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

Comment: I don't think that's the case, since the MainController class is not referenced anywhere else, so even if the solution would work, there would be no functionality

Comment: You might need to do a rebuild as well for it to pick up the change. You don't refer to the controller class directly. Spring uses annotation scanning to find all your controllers automatically.

Comment: rebuild did not help, I've tried replacing `SpringApplication` with `Application`, and it did run, but /test falls back to Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: Whoops sorry I put the wrong class name above :) Fixed now. You want to put your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class name in the run statement. If you're seeing the Whitelabel page that means your server is starting up at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92179/discussion-between-nerdherd-and-tofiffe).